# Pass a string to pytest, to a unittest class

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am calling a test file made in python, with the following:

```
py.test mytest.py
```

I did check the documentation and followed the example to add a fixture that read the argument passed, into a conftest file:

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--myoption", action="store", default="",
        help="Specify the option string")

@pytest.fixture
def myoption(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--myoption")
```

And in my unit test class, I did add the decorator to call the fixture:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("myoption")
class VariousTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_runsomething(self):
        print(myoption)
```

Although I can't get the value of my option in any way; what am I doing wrong here? All that I want is to pass a string to pytest, so it can populate a class variable in my unit test class.

Comment: See [parameterizing tests](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I did read that but it is not really that clear; I am trying to pass something like --"my parameter string", working around that example to see how to achieve it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for unit tests classes; I did try to write a conftest file as in the example, adding a fixture to read the parameter but then I have no way to retrieve the content of that parameter because when I call the fixture from my unit test class, I get an error because that function expect a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `pytest.mark.usefixtures` marker, you can't access the fixture object, but only have side effect of the fixture function.

If you want to use fixture object access in the test method, use explicitly specify fixture as a parameter:

```
import pytest

def test_runsomething(myoption):   # <--- myoption specified as parameter
    print(myoption)
```

---

```
➜  t cat t.py
import pytest

def test_runsomething(myoption):
    print(myoption)
➜  t py.test -s --myoption myoption-value t.py
==========================================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.13, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /private/tmp/t, inifile:
collected 1 items

t.py myoption-value
.

============ 1 passed in 0.00 seconds ============
```

---

If you want to use unittest.TestCase based tests, you need to modify `conftest.py` so that fixture is injected into the class:

*conftest.py*

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--myoption", action="store", default="",
        help="Specify the option string")

@pytest.fixture
def myoption(request):
    request.cls.myoption = request.config.getoption("--myoption")
    # ^-- set `myoption` attribute
```

and access it in the test method as `self.myoption` or `VariousTests.myoption`:

```
import unittest
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("myoption")
class VariousTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_runsomething(self):
        print(self.myoption)  # <----
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! I was going crazy trying to figure out how do you acccess the data; because I did follow with the debugger the parameter assignment, and it was indeed going in the fixture part of conftest.py; but for the sake of the heavens, I was not able to get any example that show how to retrieve that data afterward. All the example bring up the same as your first part of the answer; which is fine if you use directly pytest format tests; but since I have a ton of unit test already written, I just wanted to bring in the parameter in the class; and in a second time, convert the tests.

Comment: @newbiez, Sorry, but I don't get what you want to tell me.

Comment: I was pointing out that no example was mentioning that you can get the myoption, assigning the request.cls.myoption to the getoption() output in the fixture.

Comment: @newbiez, Thank you for explanation. BTW, there is an example in pytest documentation: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#mixing-pytest-fixtures-into-unittest-testcase-style-tests

Comment: Awesome; I did go up and down the official documentation and didn't notice this page :(